# On the encouragement of twins to be born

Tags: science-based, biology

What sort of evolutionary pressures would favour the prevalence of twin births?

I mean a world where all of the animals that have live births almost always give birth to twins or higher. Bonus points if you can make every plant also be two twins living together.

This should include species such as humans where they are inclined to instead of making many children, invest a lot of resources into a few. It seems that if you merely increase the number who die then they will have more pregnancies instead. In addition, a situation where say 5 children are born for 1 to grow to adulthood is not acceptable. If some people lose their twin it is acceptable but the majority should retain them.

One idea I had was to have two babies be born with some dimorphism between them. For instance you could have a species give birth to a knight and a princess. The knight is stronger than the princess and defends them and then they find another knight princess pair and the knights marry the princesses of the opposite pair. I'm not sure how practical that is. So any ideas?

Edit  I believe that this question is different to the previous one. The previous question was asking about litters amongst a single species where most of the litter died. The point of this was to have higher reproductive rates.  This question was intended to have multiple births for other purposes as it was intending to have creatures be born with a partner and ascertaining the possible reasons for this.
 In the case of the other question the intent was for a large percentage of a given litter to die and in this case if that happened it wouldn't count. It was also an attempt to see if the possibility of having dimorphism between offspring to lead to multiple types which specialise in something.

Comment: Is the knight already born on a war horse? Jokes apart, do you have any idea of the hassle to simultaneously grow two toddlers in parallel? We humans already invest a lot in growing few children.

Comment: multiple births are already common for many species. Generally it is less common for larger animals and, of course, the investment necessary in raising offspring is also a factor. I am not sure that I completely understand the question - is the intention to increase the incidence of twins, specifically, or multiple births generally?

Comment: Perhaps an interesting reference:  https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/37011/why-didnt-humans-evolve-to-reproduce-identical-twins-all-the-time

Comment: You've already asked this question twice  last week under another identity. Voting to close since those questions were also closed.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103537/increasing-the-survival-rate-of-multiple-births
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103493/increasing-the-rate-of-multiple-births-in-humanoids

Comment: @wetcircuit Something similar may have been asked before, but I was not the one to ask it and I do not and never had any other accounts on this site. I don't know why you're accusing me of making another account and not simply thinking I'm a new person who happened to ask a similar question

Answer (score 4):

In a predator species maybe it would be useful to have a default hunting partner.

In a prey species, it would be useful to have someone watching wile you eat.

For females, it would be useful to have someone help raise the young if the male of the species doesn't stay with the female to do that.

For males, it is useful to have help in cornering females in order to reproduce ([see dolphins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin#cite_note-75)).

Comment: got sources? It sounds like you're onto something here

Comment: @AricFowler Sources for what? Why? How?

Comment: @AricFowler edited the 4. point. Other points are purely speculation.

Comment: I like it.  It passes the sniff test in all respects.  These would be identical twins, improving their (identical) genetic fitness via teamwork.  If female only one would get pregnant but both would care for young.  Team competition among males also a neat idea - it would be like tag team wrestling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering CULTURAL reactions to all creatures and individuals being born as twins, or just the evolutionary benefits from a strictly biological sense?

The Biological answer is easiest. Giving birth to two or more young increases chances at least one organism survives to adulthood. Culturally? Well that's complicated. The sky is basically the limit, you could have one society that views one twin as the "real" child and the other as simply an impostor, and at a certain age the "impostor" is named and becomes a slave for the "real" child. In another maybe "individuals" are actually seen as pairs, and neither twin is considered an individual but instead only half of a whole person. Maybe the rare individuals born without twins are persecuted as only having half a soul, and twins who lose their partner commit suicide or join the ranks of the mis-treated "half-lings."

I mean I could derive possible cultural plot points until the cows come home, but I think I made my point. I hope my answer was helpful.